# Nodeclipse plugin doesn't install missing requirement

Tags: eclipse, node.js, ubuntu-12.04

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

I'm trying to install the Nodeclipse plugin for eclipse, but I just can't get it to work (I tried yesterday as well).

error msg:

```
Missing requirement: Nodeclipse 0.9.0.201401030549 (org.nodeclipse.ui 0.9.0.201401030549) requires 'package org.nodeclipse.bundle.coffee 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I'm wondering if I messed up my Eclipse/Node/Nodeclipse setup some how?
 this is what I did.

Eclipse I downloaded the latest tarbal from eclipse.org (64-bit kepler standard)
 Then simply uncompressed it.

Installed openJDK (sudo apt-get)

I added in both CDT and Aptana without issue.

Downloaded latest Node from nodejs.org

Unzipped,

```
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

Tried to do:

```
 npm install nodeclipse
 but I didn't have permissions, so I adjusted them, sudo chown ... 

 npm install nodeclipse
 npm install express
 npm install coffee-script.
```

But I still cannot get the Nodeclipse plugin

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to install 0.9.0, it looks like it had a bug that is resolved in 0.9.05:

http://dl.bintray.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse/0.9.05/